# Discover button IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity

Tags: java, android, android-nsd

Link to the 3 java files:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/f57xwvm3gu9eubm/macnetworknotify.rar?dl=0

I am trying to execute this application example found at http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html#discover about NSD. When I execute it, it says that it could not execute method of the activity when I click on the 'discover' button. All other buttons have no problem.

```
09-06 17:16:10.430  13489-13489/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.motivecodex.macnetworknotify, PID: 13489
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4253)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5197)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20926)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4248)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5197)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20926)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: listener already in use
            at android.net.nsd.NsdManager.discoverServices(NsdManager.java:559)
            at com.motivecodex.macnetworknotify.NsdHelper.discoverServices(NsdHelper.java:141)
            at com.motivecodex.macnetworknotify.MainActivity.clickDiscover(MainActivity.java:58)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4248)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5197)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20926)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
```

Some code I think might help sove the problem, I really don't know or can't find the problem.

activity_main.xml

```
<Button
 android:id="@+id/discover_btn"
 android:layout_width="96dp"
 android:layout_height="64dp"
 android:onClick="clickDiscover"
 android:text="@string/discover" />
```

MainActivity.java

```
public void clickDiscover(View v) {
        mNsdHelper.discoverServices();
    }

@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mNsdHelper != null) {
            mNsdHelper.discoverServices();
        }
    }
```

NsdHelper.java

```
public void discoverServices() {
        mNsdManager.discoverServices(
                SERVICE_TYPE, NsdManager.PROTOCOL_DNS_SD, mDiscoveryListener);
    }

public void stopDiscovery() {
        mNsdManager.stopServiceDiscovery(mDiscoveryListener);
    }
```

And, when I open NsdManager.java, where discoveryServices and NsdManager are located, I see a lot of errors, starting from the import saying cannot resolve  SdkConstant and AsyncChannel and Protocol and then a lot of erros within the code. Is this normal? Is this causing the crash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be cause by the `discoverServices(...)` method call, you're reusing the `mDiscoveryListener` listener.

[public void discoverServices (String serviceType, int protocolType, NsdManager.DiscoveryListener listener)](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/net/nsd/NsdManager.html#discoverServices(java.lang.String,%20int,%20android.net.nsd.NsdManager.DiscoveryListener))

> listener  .... Cannot be null. Cannot be in use for an active service discovery.

Comment: could it be that it does not discover any other device (that's what it want to do) and crashes therefore? Just asking, because I had a similar crash experience when I could not find anyone within facebook.

Comment: @F4LLCON I don't think so, the problem may be cause because you're calling the `discoverServices()` more then once or you're using the `mDiscoveryListener` somewhere else in your app. You can't reuse the listener until you call the `stopServiceDiscovery(NsdManager.DiscoveryListener)` method.

Comment: I don't think I am calling the discoveryServices() somewhere else and also don't use the mDiscoveryListener anywhere else.. I've added the Java files to my dropbox. Link is at the beginning of my question

Comment: @F4LLCON you're calling the `discoverServices()` multiple times, it is called in the `onResume()` method and in the `clickDiscover(...)` method.

Comment: I am calling the discoveryServices() that is inside NsdHelper from within MainActivity.java. So basically it's being called one time? The code is literally from the Google example apps found here http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html

Comment: @F4LLCON `discoveryServices()` is called multiple times (every time the activity is resumed or the button clicked) and that is what is causing the problem. Inside the `discoverServices()` you are calling `discoverServices(...)` and you're reusing the `mDiscoveryListener` listener. To fix this, you can use a mechanism to keep track if the service discovery was stopped before you start it again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you managed to make it worked, and how about adding a check flag before discovering?

```
boolean isListenerUsed = false;
```

And:

```
if (isListenerUsed == false) {
        isListenerUsed = true;
        mNsdManager.discoverServices(
                SERVICE_TYPE, NsdManager.PROTOCOL_DNS_SD, mDiscoveryListener);
}
```